# How to make with lists?

Tags: python, nested-lists

How to make a multiplication chart with nested lists and for ? I need to all numbers from first list multiply to from second list
chart = [

```
   [],
   [],
   ]
   for i in range(1,len(chart)+1):
       for j in range(i,i*len(chart)+1):
           print(f'{i} * {j} = {i*j}')
```

Comment: Okay, and what goes wrong when you try your code? Hint: what values do you want `j` to use each time through the loop? What should the lowest value be, each time that loop starts? What should the highest value be? Therefore, what `range` should you use?

Comment: Do you actually want to pull the values for `i` and `j` out of the `chart` data, or just generate them directly from the `range`? You should make sure you *clearly* understand a) how `for` loops work in Python; b) what the `range` function actually does (it is *just another function* and it has *nothing to do with* the `for` loop syntax).

Answer (score 1):

In python positions of elements in a list start from `0`.

The `chart` list contains 2 lists:

```
chart[0] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
chart[1] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

What you want to do is access the elements of the first list and multiply by elements of the second list.

```
for i in range(len(chart[0])):  # range(5) => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
    for j in range(len(chart[1])):  # range(10) => 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
        print(f'{chart[0][i]} * {chart[1][j]} = {chart[0][i] * chart[1][j]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.product` will produce the desired output, creating 2-tuples consisting of one element from the first list and one element from the second list:

```py
import itertools
chart = [
   [1,2,3,4,5],
   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
]
for i, j in itertools.product(*chart):
    print(f'{i} * {j} = {i*j}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

```
chart = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]

>>> print('\n'.join([f'{i} * {j} = {i*j}' for i in chart[0] for j in chart[1]]))
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
1 * 3 = 3
1 * 4 = 4
...
4 * 10 = 40
5 * 1 = 5
5 * 2 = 10
5 * 3 = 15
5 * 4 = 20
5 * 5 = 25
5 * 6 = 30
5 * 7 = 35
5 * 8 = 40
5 * 9 = 45
5 * 10 = 50
```